# HTML CSS, Bootstrap responsive DIV height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good day,

I am trying to make my first responsive layout with the help of the Bootstrap Framework.

As a base layout I have taken an example template and I am now trying to modify this template.

I have added the following:

```
    <div class="row col-xs-12 col-md-6 border1" id="HeadBar">
        This is not showing up
    </div>
```

Here I want to place the page header (logo and company title)

My CSS code :

```
#HeadBar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
#HeadBar h1 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The problem is.. The **#HeadBar** doesn't show up at all.
Let alone being responsive.

Adding a H1 tag does make it visible. But I want it to be visible without any additions.

I hope that anyone could see my errors.
I know this is very basic. But I need to get a hang of it

https://jsfiddle.net/ferencik/zb50wgve/

Comment: you shouldnt add `row` to divs that also have column classes. rows are wrappers for columns

Comment: this is `float` issue

Comment: Simply use a div instead of applying all kind of classes just use ID #headbar as you are using currently, it will work. @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still need some addition, like adding `z-index:1001` (or any value more than 1000 because you have class `navbar-static-top` in your nav - it have `z-index:1000` - which overlap your `#HeadBar`) in `#HeadBar`

```
#HeadBar {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 10%;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index: 9999;` to the css.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb50wgve/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `z-index`, i would recommend fixing your `position` issues which are the actual cause of the problem.

I would also remove the class `.row` from the `#headBar` div. `.row` is used for margins within a container and shouldn't be use on the parent container itself.

On `.navbar`, I have set the `position` back to `initial` as it was always fixing to the top of the parent instead of finding its place below the previous sibling.

```css
/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}
/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Special class on .container surrounding .navbar, used for positioning it into place. */

.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */

.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  position: initial;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}
/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */

.carousel {
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */

.carousel-caption {
  z-index: 10;
}
/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */

.carousel .item {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */

.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 80px 0;
  /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}
/* Thin out the marketing headings */

.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
}
/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* Navbar positioning foo */
  .navbar-wrapper {
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  /* The navbar becomes detached from the top, so we round the corners */
  .navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 21px;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
}
#HeadBar {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#HeadBar h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 border1" id="HeadBar">
      This is not showing up
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zb50wgve/3/)

Answer (score 0):

First, question to solve this is what are you trying to achieve?
this element with text should be fixed? static?

Second, the element with class `row` must wrap the elements with `col-something-number`

Thrid, If the nav is static don't break the nav component just add a div on top, see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6evtc3ry/

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

Change
Add the property in class `.navbar-wrapper .navbar`

```
 float:left;
 width:100%
```

See the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zb50wgve/4/

***OR***

**Structural** changes

Add wrap up of `.row` for `#HeadBar`.
and remove the class `row` from `#HeadBar`

Code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-xs-12 col-md-6 border1" id="HeadBar">
          This is not showing up
    </div>
</div>
```

See fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zb50wgve/5/

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap, you have to separate row DIVs with col-... ones, like this:

```
 <div class="row" id="HeadBar">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 border1">
       Something to show
     </div>
</div>
```

Because col-... divs use float system, and row allows to clear your DOM.
By the way, using % for height with a static or relative position does not work. You have to use pixels, em or what you want.

```
#HeadBar {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   min-height: 50px; // example
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
}
```

or simply use fixed or absolute property to set a pourcentage value:

```
 #HeadBar {
   background-color: #ffffff;
   height: 10%;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   display: block;
}
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: Thanks.. But now I want a higher #HeadBar : e.g. 15%; How do I do this?
Because changing the settings doesn't help.

Answer (score -1):

**Simply use a div instead of applying all kind of classes just use #headbar as you are using**

```
<div id="HeadBar" class="">
                This is not showing up
            </div>
```

This will work well

Comment: Whats the issue with this solution?  can you please tell instead of voting down - whoever done that :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this,

```
#HeadBar 
{
  display:inline-flex;
  height:10%;
  width:100%;
}
```